# WP 8.1: How to add wayPoint in a route?

Tags: dictionary, routes, windows-phone-8.1

I am new windows phone developer, my question is how to add waypoints in below code:

```
> MapRouteFinderResult routeResult=await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(startPoint,endPoint);
```

I read all article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx
but i cant find anything about how to add waypoints to calculates routes. I know that my question is feasible on windows phone 8 with some Query.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer in my question above, i used the `GetDrivingRouteFromWaypointsAsync` method. Information below  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.maps.maproutefinder.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Services.Maps.MapRouteFinder?view=winrt-20348)